# align rows if there are same strings in cell (excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to align rows of 2 colums if there are same strings in cells
I don't know which formula or vba code may I use. 

Here is an image example https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvxsc.jpg

Formatted text **before**

```
1st column          2nd column

http://alfa.com     http://gatto.com
http://beta.com     http://alfa.com
http://gatto.com    http://beta.com
```

I try to reorder so **after**

```
 1st column         2nd column

 http://alfa.com    http://alfa.com
 http://beta.com    http://beta.com
 http://gatto.com   http://gatto.com
```

Comment: With the supplied text a simple INDEX/MATCH, but with the picture the second part you are going to want Fuzzy Lookup.  It is an addon.  There are many, even Microsoft has their own.

Comment: just as your 2nd picture is, the array formula in E3 `{=INDEX(D:D,MIN(IF(MID(B3,(SEARCH("http://",B3)),9999)=MID($D$3:$D$5,(SEARCH("http://",D$3:D$5)),9999),ROW($3:$5))))}` will do (just copy down)

Comment: **@DirkReichel** I copy your formula on E3 cell and then press Enter. Nothing happens. How?

Comment: You would enter the formula `=INDEX(D:D,MIN(IF(MID(B3,(SEARCH("http://",B3)),9999)=MID($D$3:$D$5,(SEARCH("h‌ttp://",D$3:D$5)),9999),ROW($3:$5))))` then instead of enter you would hit ctrl-shift-enter.  If done properly Excel will put the `{}` around the formula you do not type them yourself.

Comment: With your supplied text, you could merely sort the columns.  With your screenshot, you have added a level of complexity.  But what is your real data like?  How complex?  Will you **ALWAYS** be matching URL's?  What about different matches in the part of the string prior to the URL?  In other words, are your examples comprehensive?  Or are they more complex than what you have provided.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes I want ALWAYS match URLs.

Comment: @PeterLong Will there only be two possible matches with the same URL, or more?  If more, how do you want to resolve conflicts? eg: Table 1 contains `jackhttp://alfa.com`; Table 2 contains `fasehttp://alfa.com` and also `titlehttp://alfa.com`

Comment: **@DirkReichel** the formula you typed contains an error. Look pic http://i.imgur.com/29pMt0W.jpg Seems something `D,MIN`

Comment: **@RonRosenfeld** Is necessary to recognize only *http://* not prefixes e.g. .  `<title>` , `jack` or anything before **http://** word. No I format text to one-to-one correlations so `http://alfa.com` is present only one time in the first column so there are not more possbile matches in 2nd column. Every *http://* link in the first column is unique value.

Comment: @PeterLong If that is the case, then `=INDEX($D$3:$D$5,MATCH("*" & MID(B3,SEARCH("http",B3),99),$D$3:$D$5,0))` will return the first value in the second table that has the same URL as the value in the first table.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld look [HERE](http://peterlongx.altervista.org/Flash/Segnalazioni/error_formula_excel.htm), please. What is wrong??

Comment: @PeterLong Perhaps your system uses the semicolon rather than the comma to separate parts of the formula.

Comment: yup, your tip is correct. I want assign you like solved, please write your answers. Only thing also: if I change position like [HERE](http://i.imgur.com/ZP59XxJ.png) formula tell me `#VALUE` ? Is there a fix? Thanks anyway

Comment: @PeterLong The formula should only be filled down as far as there are entries in Column B.  If you want to copy it down further, then wrap it in an `IFFERROR` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=INDEX($D$3:$D$5,MATCH("*" & MID(B3,SEARCH("http",B3),99),$D$3:$D$5,0))
```

will return the first value in the second table that has the same URL as the value in the first table.